# Observer design pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Is the observer design pattern already defined in STL (Like the java.util.Observer and java.util.Observable in Java) ?

Comment: Presumably as an example of another language's standard library that has the observer pattern built into it.

Comment: Is boost acceptable to you? If not I would be willing to post a standard non-boost implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a reference implementation (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Observer_pattern&oldid=342672104)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class SupervisedString;
class IObserver{
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(const SupervisedString&) = 0;
};


class SupervisedString{ // Observable class
    std::string _str;
    std::map<IObserver* const, IObserver* const> _observers;

    typedef std::map<IObserver* const, IObserver* const>::value_type item;

    void _Notify(){
        BOOST_FOREACH(item iter, _observers){
            iter.second->handleEvent(*this);
        }
    }

public:
    void add(IObserver& ref){
        _observers.insert(item(&ref, &ref));
    }

    void remove(IObserver& ref){
        _observers.erase(&ref);
    }

    const std::string& get() const{
        return _str;
    }

    void reset(std::string str){
        _str = str;
        _Notify();
    }
};


class Reflector: public IObserver{ // Prints the observed string into std::cout
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(const SupervisedString& ref){
        std::cout<<ref.get()<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Counter: public IObserver{  // Prints the length of observed string into std::cout
    virtual void handleEvent(const SupervisedString& ref){
        std::cout<<"length = "<<ref.get().length()<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    SupervisedString str;
    Reflector refl;
    Counter    cnt;

    str.add(refl);
    str.reset("Hello, World!");
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    str.remove(refl);
    str.add   (cnt);
    str.reset("World, Hello!");
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to take seriously a C++ implementation that uses illegal member function names such as _Notify.

Comment: Apparently it has other problems as well. Check the discussion page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Observer_pattern#Implementation_flaw_in_C.2B.2B

Comment: hmmm... maybe my answer should have been "Modify the code located here to a reference implementation"  :(

Comment: C++ implementation has been removed from the wikipedia article.

Comment: @NickBedford is it valid C++ because it compiles? The standard is quite clear actually: from §2.10.3.1 "Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an
uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use." I think the example should be changed, besides I see no real useful reason for the function to be prefixed with an underscore. Add §17.6.4.3.2 "If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 21):

No, but [**Boost.Signals2**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals2.html) gives you something similar.

Comment: +1, Boost.Signals is great. Also check Signals2 if you have multiple threads.

Comment: Boost.Signals is deprecated, Boost.Signals2 should be used instead.

Answer (score 8):

As far as my knowledge goes in C++, STL doesn't have an implementation for Observer pattern. There was a proposal for Signal/Slot for standard library in TR2 though.

There are plenty of libraries which provides implementation for Observer pattern Qt library being one of the pioneers. The boost library has an implementation (see Boost::Signals & Boost::Signals2).

The Poco C++ library has a neat implementation of the observer pattern (see NotificationCenter).

libsigc++, cpp-events are some of the other libraries that provide signal/slot implementations.

Answer (score 7):

No it doesn't. The C++ STL is much smaller than Java's Standard Library. If you are looking for something to expand on the STL that is supported by almost everything, it would be worth taking a look at the Boost libraries. In this case you may want to look at [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html) which provides a signal/slot model.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Subject;
class Observer {
public:
  virtual void update(Subject & subject) = 0;
};
// also knows as Observable in literature
class Subject
{
  string state;
  set<Observer*> observers;
public:
  void attachObserver(Observer *o) { observers.insert(o); }
  void detachObserver(Observer *o) { observers.erase(o); }
  void notifyObservers()
  {
    for (auto &o : observers)
    {
      o->update(*this);
    }
  }
  string getState() { return state; }
  void changeState(const string & s)
  {
    state = s;
    notifyObservers();
  }
};
class ObserverImpl : public Observer
{
  string state;
public:
  void update(Subject & sbj) override
  {
    state = sbj.getState();
  }
  string getState() { return state; }
};
int main()
{
  ObserverImpl a, b, c;
  Subject subject;
  subject.attachObserver(&a);
  subject.attachObserver(&b);
  subject.attachObserver(&c);
  subject.changeState("Observer pattern");
  cout << a.getState() << endl;
  cout << b.getState() << endl;
  cout << c.getState() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

please also see UML/flow diagrams http://codepatterns.ddns.net/

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

The [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_design_pattern) is not defined in the `STL`. You can refer to the ["Gang of four" Design Patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) or a Google search should provide enough details to implement it. If this question isn't answered soon, I'll post a quick example.

Comment: Or you can copy-paste the Wikipedia implementation that somebody has linked in another answer

Comment: thanks! Boost signals look interesting. I have used Boost for random number generation but never for an observer pattern or signals as they call it. Anyhow, I think evaluating the GOF observer pattern and Boost Signals is a good idea at least for academic purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
             #include<iostream>
             #include<string.h>
             #include<vector>
             #include<algorithm>
             using namespace std;


             class Customer;
             class flipkart
             {
                vector<Customer*>list;
                vector<Customer*>::iterator it;
                public:
                void Register(Customer *customer)
                {
                   list.push_back(customer);
                }
                void unregister(Customer *customer)
                {
                    list.erase(remove(list.begin(), list.end(),customer), list.end()); 
                }

                void notify(string item,float vprice);
             };


             class observer
             {
                 public:
                 virtual void update(string item,float vprice)=0;
             };
             class Customer:public observer
             {
                 string name;
                 public:
                 Customer(string n)
                 {
                     name=n;
                 }

                 void update(string item,float vprice)
                 {
                     cout<<"**Flipkart**updated price for "<<item<<" is:"<<vprice<<" Rupees only, request recieved by "<<name<<endl;
                 }
             };

             void flipkart::notify(string item,float vprice)
             {
                 for(it=list.begin();it!=list.end();it++)
                 {
                     (*it)->update(item,vprice);
                 }
             }

             class product:public flipkart
             {
                 public:
                 void change_price(string item,float vprice)
                 {
                     notify(item,vprice);
                 }
             };

             int main()
             {
                 Customer customer1("Dhoni"),customer2("Yuvraj"),customer3("Kohli");
                 product LCD;

                 LCD.Register(&customer1);
                 LCD.Register(&customer2);
                 LCD.Register(&customer3);

                 LCD.change_price("LCD HD2 TV",12000);

                 LCD.unregister(&customer2);
                 cout<<"after unregisterng customer2:\n";

                 LCD.change_price("LCD HD2 TV",11500);
             }
```

Comment: The above code I wrote only  for people who want to  know  the  basic  usage of  observer design pattern,please comment if any mistake thank you....@THRINATH@.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please elaborate a little e.g. how this answers the question?