# In C++ is there any way to throw an 'event' which would 'bubble' up the stack like an exception?

Tags: c++

I am making an MVC application and what I'm looking for is some way to trigger a signal or event of some sort, have it 'bubble' up to the higher level view classes, and be handled. This 'bubbling' and handling would behave exactly like the throwing and catching of an exception, except obviously execution wouldn't be stopped when an event is 'thrown' like it is with an exception.

Does any such thing exist in C++?

My rationale behind it is that the lower level model classes wouldn't need to know anything about the view for this to work. I don't want to have to pass function/object pointers to the view around everywhere.

Edit: I should probably add that my application uses standard C++, so no QT as of yet, although I may try and link it to a QT GUI. Would it be wise to included QT specific code along with standard C++ in the model classes.

Comment: [Observer Pattern in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225162/observer-design-pattern-in-c)

Comment: [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals.html)

Comment: @Robert Harvey I looked at Observer, but isn't that more geared towards multiple observers who listen in on a single object. As with this example I have the opposite. Lots of subjects, but a single observer (the GUI)

Comment: I will have a look at boost signals. Are they pretty much the thing I described in the original post?

Comment: Almost looks like you want a `std::vector<std::function<void(YourEventTypeHere const&)>>`

Comment: Such a thing makes no sense, how would the lower code handle the thing that "bubbled up" if the function doesn't stop executing?  Sounds like you want to return `boost::optional<event>` from a function.  Or use threads.

Comment: @MooingDuck The function does stop executing, but is not terminated (because no unwinding is taking place). Its execution is suspended during this "bubbling up". Then later, execution can return back to that function. Imagine if a catch could say "okay, all handled, let's return to the throw now". You can do things like this in Lisp and it's very useful. Critical for designing robust software, actually. Sometimes unwinding everything or even terminating the program simply isn't an option.

Comment: @Kaz: oh, you probably want callbacks of some sort.  I've always wanted callback-based exception handling as well.

Comment: Sure, where the callback is actually a closure, and can jump out, thereby triggering unwinding.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is restartable exceptions. These aren't implemented in C++. In C++, the search for an exception handler performs unwinding as it searches, and so by the time the handler is found, all of the information between that handler and the throw site is already discarded, making it impossible to return to the throw site.

Common Lisp has restartable exceptions (they are called conditions, and rather than being "thrown" they are "signaled").  When a condition is signaled, then a search takes place through the dynamic context for a handler. Handlers are identified using a type hierarchy, much like in C++ and other languages. But unwinding does not take place at that time. The condition handlers (by themselves, or in collaboration with restart handlers) determine where the execution will continue.  This is very useful because it allows lower level code to recover from situations, without taking unilateral steps, but rather under the guidance from higher level code.  I can see how it would be useful in a model-view-controller framework.

Since C++11 has local anonymous functions perhaps something like this can be cobbed together. Though these are not true lexical closures (they are "downward funarg" only), that is all that is needed, since handlers only need to be passed down so they can be called by lower level functions, and do not have to be returned.